# Asp.Net MVC Project with Angular 5 Continuous Integration/Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-devops, angular5

Basically, we have to automate our web application with Angular5, but unfortunately I cannot install node modules by NPM task in the New Build provided by the Visual studio team services, even though I had installed the NPM + node package on the Agent server.

I had tried with CMD task in the New Build but NPM command is not recognized by the CLI Task.

On the server, all commands are working fine if I open CLI and type NPM commands on the same path. I have attached all the settings. Please guide if I am going wrong.

@Note: I'm working on VSTS private agent.

Here are the screenshots for more references:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Angular CLI to build the application?

Comment: I am using the NPM to build the application.

Comment: What's the result if you setup a new agent? On the other hand, try to add Node Tool Installer task to install nodejs (before npm install)

Comment: You may want to try building it with a hosted agent to see if the same issue comes up.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Thanks your suggestion worked fine for me.